# SSL decode error/eof postfix

Tags: postfix, openssl

Recently started receiving this error and unable to find any solution to this, any ideas?

```
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.4 21 Jun 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.4 21 Jun 2022)
Postfix version: mail_version = 3.6.4
Dovecot version: 2.3.19.1 (9b53102964)
```

Log lines:

```
Aug  7 22:10:46 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[885716]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
Aug  7 22:11:16 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[885716]: SSL3 alert write:fatal:decode error
Aug  7 22:11:16 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[885716]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308:
```

Comment: What triggers these log lines? Is something that should be working not working?

Comment: SSL logs are enabled for postfix; the trigger for these specific lines are TLS connections (receiving/sending mail)

Comment: Consider asking this question on the Postfix mailing list, there you will usually get a competent answer quickly.